# How to know sync and async behaviour of node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand the async behaviour of node.js

```
let a = (num, callback) => {
    for (let i = 0; i<num; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }

    callback(num);
}

a(10000, (num) => {
    console.log("num is " + num)
})

console.log("Completed")
```

Output of the above code is

```
1
...
9999
num is 10000
Completed
```

Please can you help me in understanding why it is blocking till it prints 9999 and under what conditions does the node behave sync and async..??

Comment: None of this is asynchronous.  It prints in order because the `for` loop is synchronous.  And once the for loop is done, it synchronously moves on to calling the callback.

Comment: The bigger question is why do you think any of this is asynchronous?

Comment: I guess the confusion stems from the use of a callback which is one way to interact with asynchronous code, but doesn't mean the code is actually async.

Comment: What behavior did you expect?

Comment: The question is some open, recommend you read this [Understanding Asynchronous Javascript](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what's happening is you are not actually using asynchronous code. This is an example of what you are possibly trying to achieve using promises and an async function:

```
// Uses promises to delay
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function AsyncOperations() {
  // We are waiting one second before calculating
  await delay(1000);
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    sum += i;
  }
  console.log(sum);
  return sum;
}

function sumPrint() {
  // Async function will run then when its finished, we will print result
  AsyncOperations().then((result) => console.log('We got: ' + result));
  // Print 'Welcome' before AsyncOperations has finished
  console.log('Welcome');
}

sumPrint();
/* Outputs:

Welcome
499500
We got: 499500
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you have provided does not contain any asynchronous code. Like another user mentioned, the `for` loop is a synchronous code block and once started, will run to completion. The loop is not "blocking" in the async sense you seem to mean, it is just doing what it should.
For further reading on expected behavior, I recommend checking out JS Promises (with async and await) and the "Concurrency Model and Event Loop".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This code is just 100% sync.
It is running in one tick.

If you want this code to run async, you can write it like that for example:

```js
const NEXT_TICK = 0;

let a = (num, callback) => {
    for (let i = 0; i<num; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }

    setTimeout(() => callback(num), NEXT_TICK);
}

a(10000, (num) => {
    console.log("num is " + num)
})

console.log("Completed")
```

Now you can see the difference:

```
1
...
9999
Completed
num is 10000
```

Comment: this just delay execution for change order, but no explain it